# Keep data in first downloaded XLS from second sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I download data from a source with my software and store it in an .xls sheet. Such downloads are performed on regular bases and always stored in a new .xls sheet. The data looks like this:

```
Shri Ram Paint House, Jodhpur JODL-29
1   25-03-2013  Opb:OPB-7521    Sap:JOD-157 -4,501.00   4,501.00    -4,501.00
2   30-03-2013  Opb:OPB-7522    Sap:JOD-179 -3,600.00   3,600.00    -3,600.00
3   30-03-2013  Opb:OPB-7523    Sap:JOD-182 -8,348.00   8,348.00    -8,348.00
    Total           -16,449.00  16,449.00   -16,449.00
```

How can I show changes in the first sheet? (The header will always stay the same)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to show where there are differences (rather than their values) may be to copy the data from your new .xls sheet into your first sheet (say alongside, say starting in `H1`) and then in `A1` use Home > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Use a formula to determine which cells to format and enter `=A1<>H1` under Format values where this formula is true:. Then, Format, select format desired and OK. Ensure Applies to (in Manage Rules) is set to `=$A:$F` and Apply, OK if necessary.

If you want the differences by value, in `H1` enter `=IFERROR(A1-'{"new .xls"}'!A1,"")` with {...} replaced by the sheet name.

Comment: thanks both. i would like to invite you on pc remote connection please help.

Comment: i dont understand i want a big exampale.